# GeoIP and Nginx

Tags: nginx, haproxy, php-fpm, geolocation, geoip

I have a nginx with geoip, but it is not working rightly. The issue is the next:

Nginx are getting geodata from `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` instead of `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_HAPROXY_IP']`, which have the real client ip. So, the reported geodata belongs to my server ip instead of client ip.

Does anybody where could be the error to fix it?

Nginx version and compiled modules:

```
nginx -V
nginx version: nginx/1.2.3
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --prefix=/etc/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-    path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --with-pcre-jit --with-debug --with-file-aio --with-http_addition_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_geoip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_image_filter_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_secure_link_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_xslt_module --with-ipv6 --with-sha1=/usr/include/openssl --with-md5=/usr/include/openssl --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module --add-module=/usr/src/nginx/source/nginx-1.2.3/debian/modules/nginx-auth-pam --add-module=/usr/src/nginx/source/nginx-1.2.3/debian/modules/nginx-echo --add-module=/usr/src/nginx/source/nginx-1.2.3/debian/modules/nginx-upstream-fair --add-module=/usr/src/nginx/source/nginx-1.2.3/debian/modules/nginx-dav-ext-module --add-module=/usr/src/nginx/source/nginx-1.2.3/debian/modules/nginx-syslog --add-module=/usr/src/nginx/source/nginx-1.2.3/debian/modules/nginx-cache-purge
```

nginx site conf (frontend machine)

```
server {
    root /var/www/storage;

    server_name ~^.*(\.)?mydomain.com$;

    if ($host ~ ^(.*)\.mydomain\.com$) {
            set $new_host $1.mydomain.com;
    }
    if ($host !~ ^(.*)\.mydomain\.com$) {
            set $new_host www.mydomain.com;
    }

    add_header Staging true;
    real_ip_header X-HAProxy-IP;
    set_real_ip_from 10.5.0.10/32;

    location /files {
            expires 30d;
            if ($uri !~ ^/files/([a-fA-F0-9]+)_(220|45)\.jpg$) {
                    return 403;
            }
            rewrite  ^/files/([a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])([a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])([a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])([a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])([a-fA-F0-9]+)_(220|45)\.jpg$ /files/$1/$2/$3/$4/$1$2$3$4$5_$6.jpg break;
            try_files $uri @to_backend;
    }

    location /assets {
            if ($uri ~ ^/assets/r([a-zA-Z0-9]+[^/])(/(css|js|fonts)/.*)) {
                    rewrite ^/assets/r([a-zA-Z0-9]+[^/])/(css|js|fonts)/(.*)$ /assets/$2/$3 break;
            }
            try_files $uri @to_backend;
    }

    location / {
            proxy_set_header Host $new_host;
            proxy_set_header X-HAProxy-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_pass http://10.5.0.10:8080;
    }

    location @to_backend {
            proxy_set_header Host $new_host;
            proxy_pass http://10.5.0.10:8080;
    }
}
```

nginx.conf (backend machine)

```
http{
...
    ##
    # GeoIP Config
    ##
    geoip_country  /etc/nginx/geoip/GeoIP.dat; # the country IP database
    geoip_city     /etc/nginx/geoip/GeoLiteCity.dat; # the city IP database
...
}
```

fastcgi_params (backend machine)

```
### SET GEOIP Variables ###
fastcgi_param  GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE               $geoip_country_code;
fastcgi_param  GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE3              $geoip_country_code3;
fastcgi_param  GEOIP_COUNTRY_NAME               $geoip_country_name;
fastcgi_param  GEOIP_CITY_COUNTRY_CODE          $geoip_city_country_code;
fastcgi_param  GEOIP_CITY_COUNTRY_CODE3         $geoip_city_country_code3;
fastcgi_param  GEOIP_CITY_COUNTRY_NAME          $geoip_city_country_name;
fastcgi_param  GEOIP_REGION                     $geoip_region;
fastcgi_param  GEOIP_CITY                       $geoip_city;
fastcgi_param  GEOIP_POSTAL_CODE                $geoip_postal_code;
fastcgi_param  GEOIP_CITY_CONTINENT_CODE        $geoip_city_continent_code;
fastcgi_param  GEOIP_LATITUDE                   $geoip_latitude;
fastcgi_param  GEOIP_LONGITUDE                  $geoip_longitude;
```

haproxy.conf (frontend machine)

```
defaults
    log global
    option forwardfor
    option httpclose
    mode http
    retries 3
    option redispatch
    maxconn 4096
    contimeout 100000
    clitimeout 100000
    srvtimeout 100000

listen cluster_webs *:8080
    mode http
    option tcpka
    option httpchk
    option httpclose
    option forwardfor
    balance roundrobin
    server backend-stage 10.5.0.11:80 weight 1
```

`$_SERVER` dump: http://paste.laravel.com/7dy

Where `10.5.0.10` is frontend private ip and `10.5.0.11` backend private ip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure the [realip](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_realip_module.html) module in nginx to set $remote_addr for the geoip module to use:

```
real_ip_header X-HAProxy-IP;
set_real_ip_from your.haproxy.ip/32;
```

Comment: I already have that, but $remote_addr is showing my server ip instead of client ip. That's the problem

Comment: Can you add your server{} block to the post?  I don't want to just start guessing why it's not picking up the header.

Comment: Yes, sure :). I have just updated the question with it

Comment: I don't see you actually using the geoip module anywhere in here.  While I'm not sure why $remote_addr isn't being set, you should actually be able to use `proxy_set_header X-HAProxy-IP $http_x_haproxy_ip;` to have nginx pass through the header if it's not passing it through automatically.

Comment: you also seem to be passing back to haproxy.  Does it trust the X-HAProxy-IP that nginx is setting in its request, or does it overwrite it?

Comment: Added nginx.conf of backend machine, site config of backend machine and a dump of `$_SERVER`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6039/discussion-between-kolbyjack-and-javiermartinez)